# NHibernate bag is always null

Tags: nhibernate, mapping

I have set up my mapping file and classes as suggested by many articles

```
class A { ... IList BBag {get;set;} ... }

class B { ... A aObject {get;set;} ... }

<class name="A">...<bag name="BBag" table="B" inverse="true" lazy="false"><key column="A_ID" /><one-to-many class="B" /></bag>...

<class name="B">...<many-to-one name="aObject" class="A" column="A_ID" />...
```

I added a set of A's to the A table and a set of B's to the B table, all the data is stored
as expected. However if I try and access `aInstance.BBag.Count` I get a null reference exception.  I think I missing some key knowledge on how an bag gets instantiated. 
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you call Save()/SaveOrUpdate()/Update() the collections of the saved object will not be instantiated/hydrated.

As such you have to select the object again if you want the collection elements.
If you don't want to do that you can make a collection of the saved collection objects and assign them to the saved object's collection property.

Comment: I have been experimenting further today and it seems that you need to retrieve the entity again so that the collections from relatioships are retrieved.  I have a set of static entities, in a helper class, that I use for unit testing and I was updating table B and trying to access the collection of B's from class A without selecting A from the database, i.e Helper.oAObject.BCollection which is always going to be empty.  However oAObject = ARepo.GetById(Helper.oAObject.Id) and the collection will be available, even without an update table A.  What you are saying is right, select object again.

Comment: from what you are saying, you are making a logical mistake: the BCollection of B objects has nothing to do with updating table A. Consider Collections as a handy tool to fetch objects that have a correlation (like a foreign key) to this object.

Answer (score 0):

I did `ARepository.Update(BOject);` and when I called it back it worked for some reason I thought the update would happen automatically.  Is there a way to do automatically update a bag, i.e. some mapping file setting?